# Vuex action returning jQuery promise doesn't work, .fail is not a function

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, jquery-deferred

I have a vuex action like this

```
myAction() {
    const deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(() => deferred.resolve(), 3000);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

in my vue component

```
myMethod() {
    this.myAction().fail(() => ...do something...);
}
```

throwing error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.myAction(...).fail is not a function

The code was working fine, but issue appeared once I updated my npm modules/vue-cli/webpack etc. Another point is if I change `.fail` to `.catch` then it works fine. But the question is why `.fail` is not working?

Comment: What you describe would happen if `myAction` failed to explicitly return the jQuery promise (it would return an implicit wrapper promise instead). Did you test the simplified example above and still get the error? Just wondering if your actual action is different enough from the example.

Comment: thats exactly what I have tried, this.myAction().catch(...) is working but this.myAction().fail is not

Comment: I m using vuex 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with Vuex 3.4.0, actions always return a native promise.  In past versions, Vuex only checked whether an action returned a *thennable* object, i.e. anything with `.then` property.  If not, it wrapped the action return value in a new promise.  But if so, it simply returned the object without wrapping it, assuming it was a promise.  Starting with 3.4.0, Vuex wraps even thennable objects.

So in the past, the `$.Deferred` promise was able to slip by, because it has a `.then` method which returns a `$` promise object with a `.fail` method.  But now it gets wrapped in a native promise.

---

## registerAction

If you inspect the Vuex source, you see that `registerAction` didn't change from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0.  This is where non-thennable return values are wrapped in promises.  It hasn't changed:

```js
function registerAction (store, type, handler, local) {
  ...
  if (!isPromise(res)) {
    res = Promise.resolve(res);
  }
  ...
}
```

---

## store.dispatch.prototype

But `store.dispatch.prototype` did change.  It used to just return the `.then` method:

```js
return result.then(function (res) {
  ...
})
```

But now it always returns a promise wrapper:

```js
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  result.then(function (res) {  // Doesn't return the inner promise either
    ...
  })
})
```

And the wrapper doesn't bother to return the inner result either.  It seems Vuex has decided to normalize the return value of actions so that it's guaranteed to be a native promise.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/89Lsqwhe/) I used when testing some stuff